# Update Properties across Viewmodels with CommunityToolkit.Mvvm and Dependency Injection

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-injection, messaging, community-toolkit-mvvm

I am trying to implement a simple WPF Application, with two nested UserControls inside the Mainwindow, and each UserControl having their own viewmodel. One Viewmodel implements a command which allows the user to choose a Directory. When a folder is chosen inside the first viewmodel, it is supposed to send a message to all other registered viewmodels. So we have three views, three viewmodels (including MainViewModel) and the Dependency Container. Though I implemented IRecipient, the ReceiverVM does not update its property.

Here are my Viewmodels, for convenience I've put them in the same file:

```
namespace MessagingReproduction;

public partial class MainViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{

}

public partial class SenderViewModel : ObservableRecipient
{
    
    private string selectedDirectory;
    public string SelectedDirectory
    {
        get => selectedDirectory;
        set
        {
            var oldValue = selectedDirectory;
            SetProperty(ref selectedDirectory, value);
            Messenger.Send<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>(new PropertyChangedMessage<string>(this, nameof(SelectedDirectory), oldValue, selectedDirectory));
        }
    }

    // simulate a FolderDialog
    [RelayCommand]
    private void SelectDirectory()
        => this.SelectedDirectory = "C:";
}

public partial class ReceiverViewModel : ObservableRecipient, IRecipient<PropertyChangedMessage<string>>
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string selectedDirectory;

    public void Receive(PropertyChangedMessage<string> message)
    {
        selectedDirectory = message.NewValue;
    }
}
```

My ReceiverView.xaml:

```
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDirectory, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Width="120" Height="22"/>
    </Grid>
```

my SenderView.xaml:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Command="{Binding SelectDirectoryCommand}"
                Width="120" Height="22"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding SelectedDirectory, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                   Width="120" Height="22"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

The MainWindow:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <local:SenderView DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
        <local:ReceiverView DockPanel.Dock="Bottom"/>
    </StackPanel>
```

The Setup for Dependency Injection insinde App.xaml.cs:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            Services = ConfigureServices();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public new static App Current => (App)Application.Current;
        public IServiceProvider Services { get; }
        private static IServiceProvider ConfigureServices()
        {
            var services = new ServiceCollection();
            services.AddTransient<MainViewModel>();
            services.AddTransient<SenderViewModel>();
            services.AddTransient<ReceiverViewModel>();

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

Setting Datacontexts inside each view like so:

```
        public ReceiverView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = App.Current.Services.GetService<ReceiverViewModel>();
        }
```

Despite the implementation of IRecipient, the viewmodels do not communicate. Note that my Views, except the Mainwindow, are UserControls.

Comment: Since you're registering your VMs as Transient, a new instance of the view model will be  created everytime the corresponding view is recreated. That might result in your VMs seemingly not updating. Try changing the `services.AddTransient<SomeViewModel>();` to `services.AddSingleton<SomeViewModel>();` and see if that resolves the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately, changing to AddSingleton didn't bring any changes.

Comment: @MichalDiviš It ended up working, but only after I brought both Receiver- and Senderviewmodel together inside the MainViewModel. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am only learning to use the MVVM toolkit myself, but it seems your are not implementing any message and also you are not registering your ReceiverViewModel as a recipient for the message.

First, create the message:

```
public class ChangeDirectoryMessage : ValueChangedMessage<string>
{
    public ChangeDirectoryMessage(string newDirectory) : base(newDirectory)
    {        
    }
}
```

Then, register the message in the receiving class:

```
public class ReceiverViewModel : ObservableObject, IRecipient<ChangeDirectoryMessage>
{
    [ObservableProperty]
    private string selectedDirectory;

    public ReceiverViewModel()
    {
        WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Register<ChangeDirectoryMessage>(this);
    }

    public void Receive(ChangeDirectoryMessage message)
    {
        selectedDirectory = message.NewValue;
    }
}
```

And finally send a message from anywhere when the selected directory has changed:

```
WeakReferenceMessenger.Default.Send(new ChangeDirectoryMessage(selectedDirectory));
```

There is a good example on how to use this messenger in the documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger

Comment: I have been tinkering with the library for some time now, and my understanding is that you do not have to use the Register-Method in your ReceiverViewModel-Constructor IF you implement IRecipient. For reference, download the sample app from Microsoft Store and go to the Messaging-Section. But just by looking at your implementation I can tell that it's going to work. My problem was that I didn't put the viewmodels in the same scope, e.g. a mainviewmodel.